# Evaluate $\sum^{n}_{i=1}(10^{i+1}-10^i)$

Tags: proof-verification, summation

> Evaluate $$\sum^{n}_{i=1}(10^{i+1}-10^i)$$

Here's what I did

$$\sum^{n}_{i=1}(10^{i+1}-10^i)
\\ = 10(\sum^n_{i=1} 1^{i+1}-1^i)
\\ = -10(\sum^n_{i=1} 1^i-1^{i+1})
\\= -10(1^n-1^{n+1})
\\= 10^{n+1}-10^n$$

Is this correct?

Comment: That's also not the right answer...

Comment: **Hint** $ $ The sum *telescopes*, e.g. [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1838240/242), and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1803901/242) for a vivid 2-dimensional example. I don't recommend the linked Wikipedia telescopy article - there are better [expositions and examples here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A242+telescopy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not correct.

One may observe that we are dealing with a [telescoping sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series):
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n\left(u_{i+1}-u_i \right)=u_{n+1}-u_1,
$$ here we have $u_i=10^i$ giving

> $$
> \sum^{n}_{i=1}(10^{i+1}-10^i)=10^{n+1}-10^1.
> $$

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple conceptual errors in the OP.

The sum of interest is of the general form

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n (a_{i+1}-a_i)&=(a_{2}-a_1)+(a_3-a_2)+(a_4-a_3)+\cdots +(a_n-a_{n-1}) +(a_{n+1}-a_n)\\\\&=a_{n+1}-a_1
\end{align}$$

For $a_i=10^i$, we obtain

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (10^{i+1}-10^i)=10^{n+1}-10$$

Comment: Nice. I first thought of two geometric series, but telescoping is something I didn't think of. +1

Comment: @joanpemo Thank you Joan!

Answer (score 4):

The wrong step you made is factoring $10$ out of the summation. You basically said this:
$$10^{i+1}-10^i=10(1^{i+1}-1^i)$$
Substitute $i=1$ into the above equation. Do you see why it doesn't work know?

What you were supposed to notice is that you can do this by telescoping, [as @OliverOloa pointed out](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1839423/307483). For more on telescoping series, look at [this example from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 2):

It should be as follows,you have made a mistake.
$$\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n } (10^{ i+1 }-10^{ i })=\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ { 10 }^{ i }\left( 10-1 \right) =9\sum _{ i=1 }^{ n }{ { 10 }^{ i } }  } =9\left( 10+{ 10 }^{ 2 }+...+{ 10 }^{ n } \right) =9\frac { 10\left( 1-{ 10 }^{ n } \right)  }{ 1-10 } ={ 10 }^{ n+1 }-10$$